# $p!$ can not divide some special numbers

Tags: number-theory

Let $p$ be the greatest prime which is not more than $n$. We write $\frac{n!}{p!}=\prod_{i=1}^kp_i^{e_i}$ with $p_i$ prime and $e_i\geq 1$. Isn't it true that $p!$  divide  the product $p_i^{\tfrac{e_i(e_i-1)}{2}}(p_i-1)(p_i^2-1)\cdots (p_i^{e_i}-1)$ for all $i$?

p.s This question is origined from group theory, whether there exists a faithful representation of the alternating group $A_p$ of dimension $e_i$ over the field $F_{p_i}$ or not?

Comment: Did you mean $p_i^{e_{\color{red}{i}}}$ in the product?

Comment: Am I correct that you asking for a proof that $p!$ does not divide the product?  ("Does $p!$ not divide ..." seems to mean "Isn't is true that $p!$ divides ..." to me, but I don't think that's what you intend.)

Comment: Sorry,  $p_i^{e_k}$ should be $p_i^{e_i}$ in the product.  Thanks!

Comment: You can edit your posts to correct typos like this (or make other changes.)  I've already fixed this one.

Comment: I don't understand the role of $n$ is the group theory question ? Did you mean $A_n$ (instead of $A_p$) ?

Comment: Here is $A_p$ and $p$ is the greatest prime which is not more than $n$.